# How to make Oracle SQL Developer export NLS-safe SQL dumps?

Tags: import, oracle11g, export, oracle-sqldeveloper, locale

I used Tools -> Database Export in Oracle SQL Developer 18.2.0 to generate full schema and data dump.

Then I attempted to use that dump in a shell script calling sqlplus and got the following error:

```
Insert into CONN.ACCOUNT (ID,CUSTOMER_ID,LAST_MODIFIED) values ('1','1',
to_timestamp('2018.09.06 17:45:29,000000000','RRRR.MM.DD HH24:MI:SSXFF'))

             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
```

Most probably, that was caused by NLS settings in Oracle SQL Developer 18.2.0. I did not touch them, SQL Developer seems to have picked them up from default Windows settings.

Is there any way to make Oracle SQL Developer generate safe export dumps that could be later imported through sqlpus without manually hunting for all required NLS settings and adding them at the beginning of the sql dump file?

Comment: There aren't really 'safe' NLS settings; by definition really they're session-specific, so you have to make sure the source (SQL Developer) and target environments are set up the same. The main thing is to check the language and territory match - so the `NLS_LANG` setting in the shell that runs SQL\*Plus matches the SQL Developer preferences. That should handle most differences, but you might have to still set date formats explicitly. You could run a query in SQL Developer to give you all the required settings, rather than hunting for them.

Comment: Those scripts are designed to be ran in SQLDev, but also what Alex says